# 配列に直前5秒間に入力されたデータだけを残し、前から毎秒削除していく方法を教えて下さい

Tags: ruby

Ruby初心者です。配列に関する質問です。

毎秒とあるハッシュ形式のデータを複数（データの数は毎秒変わり、0個の時もあります）配列の最後に追加しながら、現在時刻マイナス5秒間のデータだけが常に配列に残され、6秒以上前のデータが全て削除されていくようにするコードを使いたいのですが、調べても方法が分からず、質問させていただきました。

毎秒１つの配列を作り、配列の配列を作る方法も考えましたが、コードまで落とし込むことができませんでした。

教えていただけると非常に助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ハッシュ形式のデータとのことですが、具体的にはどのような形式でしょうか？タイムスタンプはどのように格納されていますか？

Comment: 「追加されるハッシュのデータ」と「作成される配列」の例があると具体的な回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: 私の代わりにコードを書いてください、という質問はこのサイトでは好まれません。コードまで落とし込むことができませんでした、ということですが、それにしても、できた部分はあるはずです。いきなり最終結果を求めるのではなく、今できていることと、その次に進むためにわからないこと、を整理して質問されるとよいと思います。

Comment: @cubick ご指摘ありがとうございます。以後気をつけます。

Comment: @suzukis 利用歴が浅く、そのような傾向を知りませんでした。ご指摘を受け止め、以後気をつけます。ご教示ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hash_array = [ hash_data1, hash_data2, … ] # 毎秒のHash dataの配列を作る 0個の時は空の配列
array.push(hash_array)
array.shift if array.count > 5
```

確実に毎秒動くのなら、こんな感じでも良いんじゃないですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私の質問方法が悪かったのですが、１から書いていただき恐縮です。時間ベースの処理にとらわれすぎていてarray.countを使う発想が欠落していました。その処理を毎秒ループさせればうまくいきそうです。重ねてありがとうございました。